# Dont have write permission on a mounted ntfs drive

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, mount, ntfs

I have a dual boot system and multiple drives created in SSD.
One partition is "Data" partition created from windows system and is of type ntfs.

While accessing this drive from my Ubuntu OS, I am not able to do any modification i.e. create/delete.

Note: Until few days back I was able to create folder and write to this partition.
Since I am able to read files from it and also copy to my primary partition of Ubuntu. So I think mounting is proper.
Also I can see I have full permission on folders inside this drive.

System Details:
Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Please let me know if more details are required related to this.

Comment: Probably the partition was "improved" by Windows, and got mounted `ro` (Read Only). Use `mount` or `cat /etc/mtab` to see.

Comment: Windows updates turn fast start up back on, which sets hibernation flag. Then Linux NTFS cannot mount read/write. https://superuser.com/questions/1231582/hdd-with-windows-boot-locked-because-of-hibernation-flag & http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: @waltinator yes after running cat /ect/mtab i can see that partition have ro permission, in fact, user_id and group_id are both 0 ... whats the solution to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the proper link to this issue...
[How to make the mounted ntfs partition read-write enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

In my case it was the fast startup feature of the Windows that was causing this issue.

Only thing which I was not able to figure out was it happened unexpectedly since things were working fine and without any change in windows it stoped working, it shouldn't have worked in the very beginning too.

Anyways problem is resolved now.

Thanks @oldfred for your comment.